# Best Method to Present a Many to Many Form to User

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, html

I have a questions about how to best present a form based off a many to many relationship to a user.  I'll explain my models to help give an idea of what data I need to present.

```
Models and Relationships
   Shipment  has_many :products :through => :shipment_products
   Product   has_many :shipments :through => :shipment_products
   ShipmentProducts belongs_to :shipment,  belongs_to :product
```

So basically I have A shipment form that has the necessary data to create a bill of lading.  In addition to that form,  I need to select multiple products and their quantities.  I've had a similar issue in the past where I used drag and drop, but I was unhappy with the experience being a little cumbersome.  In this case I believe there would be too many products to list in a container to be able to drag and drop.

So what I need is a form that will allow me to fill out the shipment data, search for a product, select the product,  add the quantity, and associate that with a shipment.  What is the most effective way of designing my form so these items are presented clearly to my end user?

Answer (score 0):

A popula solution fpor that is TokenInput thats a jQuery plugin that comunicates with your application via JSON. You can get it here: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Theres also a railscast dealing with that problem....

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Hope this works for you,...